# Send url in the request payloadf for expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm facing an issue while reading the url in the request body sent by the front-end.

from front end:
`{ "documentTypeId": 3, "imageUrl": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1455185376876826625/s1AjSxph_400x400.jpg" }`

but in the console log of expressjs backend
`{ documentTypeId: 3, imageUrl: 'https:&#x2F;&#x2F;pbs.twimg.com&#x2F;profile_images&#x2F;1455185376876826625&#x2F;s1AjSxph_400x400.jpg' }`

Comment: could you please share the code, middleware or handler?

Comment: I'm just using only one middleware which is 

``app.use(express.json());``

Comment: you need to use bodyparser middleware:
http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: i tried using the ``bodyParser.json()`` but still not working. The request payload will be in ``application/json`` format

Comment: you need to also add this:
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json

seperately after bodyParser.json() like this:
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

Comment: My bad, i forgot that i'm using  express-validator``body("imageUrl").not().isEmpty().trim().escape()``  which is convert the url into that format. changing it to ``body("imageUrl").not().isEmpty().trim()`` working fine now. Thank you for your support

Comment: yes it is working fine now.